# Copy image to clipboard and past on default apps Android

Tags: android, image, clipboard

I want to implement copy image to clipboard functionality in my app. 
I want to past my image on another applications for example polaris and ets. I try same codes but they not past my image on polaris. Someone know how it implement.

For example:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/1.png";
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "Image/png");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, path);

ContentResolver theContent = getContentResolver();
Uri imageUri =theContent.insert(   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

Comment: I dont understand whats you meen with this "are you able to copy image to clipboard"
For example I tried such code: